# Numpy: Why doesn't 'a += a.T' work?

Tags: python, numpy

As stated in scipy lecture notes, this will not work as expected:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 1000))
a += a.T
assert np.allclose(a, a.T)
```

But why? How does being a view affect this behavior?

Comment: The "being a view" does not affect the outcome. `b = a.T + 0` (so `b` is not a view of a, but a copy) still results in `np.allclose(a, b)` being `False`.

Comment: I don't have a `python` session to test this, but I suspect it's a buffering issue.  What happens with a small array, one where you can examine the actual values?

Comment: I thought OP was crazy, and then I ran some examples. On my system, the above works for `n` up to around 90. Then it doesn't, unless you instead do `a = a + a.T`. Then it works (as expected) up to any `n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a += a.T
```

does in-place summing up (it's using view a.T while processing), so you end up with a non-symmetric matrix
you can easily check this, i.e. I got:

```
In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
array([[ 6, 15,  7, ...,  8,  9,  2],
       [15,  6,  9, ..., 14,  9,  7],
       [ 7,  9,  0, ...,  9,  5,  8],
       ..., 
       [ 8, 23, 15, ...,  6,  4, 10],
       [18, 13,  8, ...,  4,  2,  6],
       [ 3,  9,  9, ..., 16,  8,  4]])
```

You can see it's not symmetric, right? (compare right-top and left-bottom items)

if you do a real copy:

```
a += np.array(a.T)
```

it works fine, i.e.:

```
In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[ 2, 11,  8, ...,  9, 15,  5],
       [11,  4, 14, ..., 10,  3, 13],
       [ 8, 14, 14, ..., 10,  9,  3],
       ..., 
       [ 9, 10, 10, ..., 16,  7,  6],
       [15,  3,  9, ...,  7, 14,  1],
       [ 5, 13,  3, ...,  6,  1,  2]])
```

To better understand why it does so, you can imagine you wrote the loop yourself as following:

```
In [8]: for i in xrange(1000):
            for j in xrange(1000):
                a[j,i] += a[i,j]
   ....:         

In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[ 4,  5, 14, ..., 12, 16, 13],
       [ 3,  2, 16, ..., 16,  8,  8],
       [ 9, 12, 10, ...,  7,  7, 23],
       ..., 
       [ 8, 10,  6, ..., 14, 13, 23],
       [10,  4,  6, ...,  9, 16, 21],
       [11,  8, 14, ..., 16, 12, 12]])
```

It adds a[999,0] to calculate a[0,999] but a[999,0] already has sum of a[999,0] + a[0,999] -- so below the main diagonal you add the values twice.

Comment: `a = a + a.T` is enough to circumvent the issue/bug  like show in my answer, `a += np.array(a.T)` or `a += np.copy(a.T)` doesn't seem to be necessary

Comment: this is implementation-dependent.one needs to check docs carefully before choosing the right implementation. my suggested way is a safe way -- it will always work.

Comment: I am pretty sure `a = a + a.T` should always work since it is creating a new array and is not using inplace addition at all.

Comment: I mostly focused on explaining how it works.
Technically, all options to fix this using numpy powers are about the same, they all create an additional 1000x1000 array.

Comment: Yes, you're right that a = ... should always do the right thing in Python because it has to create additional array. That's how it's implemented.
But in general, one can't trust programming languages in that way -- that's why I tell that it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: `np.add.at` can be used to implement that unbuffered iterative example.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is due to internal designs of numpy.
It basically boils down to that the inplace operator will change the values as it goes, and then those changed values will be used where you were actually intending for the *original* value to be used.

This is discussed in [this bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5241), and it does not seem to be fixable.

The reason why it works for smaller size arrays seems to be because of how the data is buffered while being worked on.

To *exactly* understand why the issue crops up, I am afraid you will have to dig into the internals of numpy.

Comment: +1 for GitHub issue link! and agree with the GH issue op, some sort of warning would have been a better user experience since we know from his example the problem is at the addition level and not the comparison level (like how this SO question shows the issue)

Answer (score 1):

> assert np.allclose(a, a.T)

I just understood now that you are generating a symmetric matrix by summing `a` with it's transponse `a.T` resulting in a symmetric matrix)

Which makes us rightfully expect `np.allclose(a, a.T)` to return true (resulting matrix being symmetric so it should be equal to its transpose)

> a += a.T # How being a view affects this behavior?

I've just narrowed it down to this

**TL;DR `a = a + a.T` is fine for larger matrices, while `a += a.T` gives strange results starting from 91x91 size**

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 1000))
>>> a += a.T  # using the += operator
>>> np.allclose(a, a.T)
False
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 1000))
>>> a = a + a.T # using the + operator
>>> np.allclose(a, a.T)
True
```

I've got same cut-off at size 90x90 like @Hannes (I am on Python 2.7 and Numpy 1.11.0, so there are at least two environments that can produce this)

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (90, 90))
>>> a += a.T
>>> np.allclose(a, a.T)
True
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (91, 91))
>>> a += a.T
>>> np.allclose(a, a.T)
False
```

Comment: `a` is not any matrix. It is symmetric since it is the sum of a square matrix and its transpose.

Comment: Also, while your example works for `n=4`, try setting it to `n=1000` and see that OP actually has a point.

Comment: But yes I a += a.T would result in a being symmetric

Comment: But it's not if you do exactly like OP describes. I.e: `a = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(1000, 1000)); a += a.T; print(np.allclose(a, a.T)`. This was with Python 3.5 and numpy 1.10.4.

Comment: Your example is **not using** inplace addition, which is what is making things weird.

Answer (score 1):

For large arrays, the in-place operator causes you to apply the addition to the operator currently being operated on. For example:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 1000))
>>> a
array([[9, 4, 2, ..., 7, 0, 6],
       [8, 4, 1, ..., 3, 5, 9],
       [6, 4, 9, ..., 6, 9, 7],
       ..., 
       [6, 2, 5, ..., 0, 4, 6],
       [5, 7, 9, ..., 8, 0, 5],
       [2, 0, 1, ..., 4, 3, 5]])
```

Notice that the top-right and bottom-left elements are 6 and 2.

```
>>> a += a.T
>>> a
array([[18, 12,  8, ..., 13,  5,  8],
       [12,  8,  5, ...,  5, 12,  9],
       [ 8,  5, 18, ..., 11, 18,  8],
       ..., 
       [19,  7, 16, ...,  0, 12, 10],
       [10, 19, 27, ..., 12,  0,  8],
       [10,  9,  9, ..., 14, 11, 10]])
```

Now notice that the top-right element is correct (8 = 6 + 2). However, the bottom-left element is the result not of 6 + 2, but of 8 + 2. In other words, the addition that was applied to the bottom-left element is the top-right element of the array *after the addition*. You'll notice this is true for all the other elements below the first row as well.

I imagine this works this way because you do not need to make a copy of your array. (Though it then looks like it *does* make a copy if the array is small.)